# Dump Analysis issue

Tags: c++, windbg

I tried to catch the stack trace of an address, but it always show me nothing,

my issue is analyse memory leak, so i have queried all heap statics and then queried highest allocated memory, it returned me lot of allocation,

and i tried to search many of allocation address by “!heap -p –a ####“, #### is adress.
but it never return me any call stack,

but if I search this address/any other adresses in memory, it shows me similar allocation.

also if i try to run this command “dt ntdll!_DPH_HEAP_BLOCK StackTrace  ####,” , it return me NULL stack trace.

is it because of page heap for application is not enabled????

Comment: Did you run gflags.exe first?

Comment: No, as i got dump from field.  but is it necessary to enable page heap  for application

Answer (score 0):

For native memory issues, you cannot easily use dumps to determine the root cause.

Microsoft has a tool DebugDiag for 32 bit processes,

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en

You can use it to track native memory leaks in some typical scenarios,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919790

Besides, involving Microsoft support team can speed up the root cause analysis,

http://support.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things here, firstly you will not get a complete stack trace for symbols you do not have access to, for this you need the pdbs without the private symbols stripped.

For the microsoft symbols entering '.symfix;.reload' in WinDbg should fix that problem.

Secondly although you will not get a stack trace for 3rd party dlls you will for your own application dlls, you will need to make sure your pdbs with public symbols match the version used to generate the dump.

You could ask the customer to generate the user stack trace in gflags and reproduce the error or to send you the pdbs with full symbol information.

It is also possible to open the dump file in Visual studio:

1. File->Open->Project/Solution navigate to dump file and click ‘OK’
2. In Solution Explorer right click project->Debug->Start new instance

You may find this approach more familiar but you will not have access to WinDbg tools but as this is a post mortem analysis you can open the dump in visual studio and WinDbg as you are not invasively debugging anyway.